# Flow Element Error

Tags: error, flow

I have a working flow that ends with an email alert action built outside the Flow designer (not the Send Email static action). This email alert goes to the owner of the new record created by the same Flow (triggered by a workflow). Now, the email alert works fine when I'm running it but it produces this error if a rep initiates it:

```
FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|Action name not found: Project_Setup__c.New_Project_Setup
|FlowActionCall|Send_Alert_to_Owner
FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|Action name not found: Project_Setup__c.New_Project_Setup
```

User is enabled as a Flow user and has access to the folder where the template for the email alert is stored. I'm clueless on what could be causing it to error out on that element. Appreciate anyone who can offer an explanation for this behavior :)

Comment: Just wondering if you ever resolved this problem and if so, how? I am having a similar issue and I am unable to resolve.
Thanks
Chris

Comment: Have you checked the permissions to that object? Both the profile of the user and the organization wide defaults/sharing rules? Are there any potential workflows that cause re-assignment? Does the user have access to any Apex classes used?